# Disable Material UI Tabs indicator animation with a prop

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tabs

I am using [Material UI tabs](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/) for my navigation menu.

I want to disable the animation from the indicator when navigating to another route.

I know there is a object prop `TabIndicatorProps`. But what is the key inside it to disable the animation? Or is it not there and do I have to do it with CSS?

```
<Tabs
 value={value}
 TabIndicatorProps={{ ?? }}
>
```

Answer (score 6):

```
<Tabs
  value={value}
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    style: { display: 'none' }
  }}
>
```

If you want to remove the **indicator** of *MUI* Tab, you need to give {display: "none"} prop inside of Tabs' TabIndicatorProps prop.

It will work correctly at any time to remove indicator of **MUI Tabs**. Good luck.

Comment: That would remove it instead of disabling the animation

Answer (score 5):

Looks like the easiest way to do this is with CSS, like this:

```js
<Tabs
  value={value}
  TabIndicatorProps={{
    style: {transition: 'none'}
  }}
>
```

Tested on Material UI version 4.11. I found this by looking at [source code (version 4.x)](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.x/packages/material-ui/src/Tabs/TabIndicator.js#L13) for the `TabIndicator` component.

This should work in Material 5.x, because it also uses `transition` CSS property, see [source code for latest version](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/3abec3b71edaae312e9ea8a0da38e37ce8ace40b/packages/mui-material/src/Tabs/Tabs.js#L201).

Answer (score 2):

in mui 5, you can do it like this

```
<Tabs
  sx={{ '& .MuiTabs-indicator': { display: 'none' } }}
>
</Tabs>
```

Answer (score 2):

Hiden: true worked for me (:

(Mui v5)

```
<Tabs
 value={value}
 TabIndicatorProps={{ hidden: true }}
>
```

P.S: I then noticed that I don't need a `Tabs`&`Tab`s components, but rather a simple `Box` with `Buttons`. AND THEN I came upon the `AppBar`&`ToolBar` which are exactly what I need (: (link: https://mui.com/material-ui/react-app-bar/#app-bar-with-responsive-menu)